# What is the use of body-parser?

Tags: node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/index.htm', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.htm" );
})

app.post('/process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {

   // Prepare output in JSON format
   response = {
       first_name:req.body.first_name,
       last_name:req.body.last_name
   };
   console.log(response);
   res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

1. `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');`
2. `var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })`
3. `app.post('/process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res)`

Can anyone please explain the purpose of above three lines of code and what is the use of body-parser?

Answer (score 3):

1. The bodyParser will populate the req.body property with the parsed body from the request. With the Line 1 you will just get one to you use in your class via require.
2. Returns middleware that only parses urlencoded bodies. This parser accepts only UTF-8 encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings. The extended option allows to choose between parsing the URL-encoded data with the querystring library (when false) or the qs library (when true). The "extended" syntax allows for rich objects and arrays to be encoded into the URL-encoded format, allowing for a JSON-like experience with URL-encoded.
3. With the last line you just saying that this route you has defined will use the bodyparser you have defined

the most of the stuff i have copied from https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser. so may take a look at this link

Answer (score 1):

1. Suppose you have `POST` route handler that accepts some parameters and works accordingly. Now you make a request from your front end app or mobile app. You pass some parameters to this request. Now what body Parser does is it extracts the parameter from the request, parses it and makes it available req.body and you can access the parameters by their specific name
2. This is a middleware and it parses `UTF-8` encoded bodies. It helps to parse URL encoded data like `JSON` objects
3. This is a way of defining that a particular route will make use of the `urlEncodedParser`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.listen(//your port)
```

// Thats it